# Using the Fold function with multiple parameter inputs

Tags: iteration

I want to construct something like: `f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, x]]]]]]`. I believe this can be done using the Fold or Nest function, but I don't know how to make it work with multiple inputs. I want to be able to create this nested/folded output to arbitrary lengths.

I have tried to use the Fold function with braces on a, b, and c, but it still has the braces in the output. Specifically, I tried: `Fold[f, x, {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c} , {a, b, c}}]` but the output still has braces.

I have looked through the references https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html, but neither page has an example with multiple inputs.

Comment: `Nest[f[a, b, c, #] &, x, 6]`

Answer (score 7):

You could use [`Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest) instead:

```
Nest[f[a, b, c, #]&, x, 6]
```

> f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, x]]]]]]

If the parameters `a`, `b` and `c` can change, then you could do something like the following instead:

```
Fold[f[Sequence@@##2, #1]&, x, {{a, b, c}, {a, b, c}, {a, b, c}}]
```

> f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, f[a, b, c, x]]]

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out: `Fold[f, x, ConstantArray["a, b, c", {6}]]`

I'll have to change the function definition so that the parameters are in the right order, but otherwise it works.

Comment: I don't think the output is what you want, since the "a, b, c" part is a string, not 3 arguments.